# JAXB in CQ5.6.1 - com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 not found

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, aem

I am facing issue in using JAXB in CQ5.6.1. I am trying to do marshalling and unmarshalling of xml messages. However I always get the below exception

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 not found
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I already tried Binding the jar file to an OSGi bundle using Maven and install in CQ, Adding jar file to the classpath and Adding the jar file to the apps/myproject/install folder. But the issue still exists. Desperate to resolve this. Appreciate any suggestion to resolve. Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is how the JAXBContext is obtained, and the exception is thrown from this line.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(s, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 0):

For any dependency, first you just need to add via bundle console in felix. Then Check it via http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder. This will show you the dependency info. Just add this info into your pom.xml [in maven]. Then build the code. Also confirm if this also exists in .m2 folder.

Thanks

Comment: I was doing the reverse. I first downloaded the jaxb-impl-1.0.6.jar that has this missing class, installed it in Maven repository, verified that it exist in .m2 folder, updated the POM file, build the project, installed the OSGi via bundle console in felix. If I need to follow your way, what is that I need to add via bundle console in the first step you mentioned? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This will be  com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 related jar file.